# Scala Parser, why doesn't "pat <~ pat ~> pat" work?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

Trying out a simple parser combinator, I'm running into compilation errors.

I would like to parse -- "Smith, Joe" into its Name object like Name(Joe, Smith). Simple enough, I guess.

Here is the code related with that:

```
    import util.parsing.combinator._

    class NameParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
      lazy val name: Parser[Name] = 
        lastName <~ "," ~> firstName ^^ {case (l ~ f) => Name(f, l)}
      lazy val lastName = stringLiteral
      lazy val firstName = stringLiteral
    }

    case class Name(firstName:String, lastName: String)
```

And I'm testing it via

```
object NameParserTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val parser = new NameParser()
    println(parser.parseAll(parser.name, "Schmo, Joe"))
  }
}
```

Getting a compilation error:

```
error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : NameParser.this.~[a,b]
required: java.lang.String
lazy val name: Parser[Name] = lastName <~ "," ~> firstName ^^ {case (l ~ f) => Name(f, l)}
```

What is that I am missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this line here:

```
  lazy val name: Parser[Name] = 
    lastName <~ "," ~> firstName ^^ {case (l ~ f) => Name(f, l)}
```

you don't want to use both `<~` and `~>`. You're creating a parser that matches `","` and `firstName` and keeps only `","`, and then you're creating a parser that matches `lastName` and the previous parser and keeps only `lastName`.

You can replace it with this:

```
(lastName <~ ",") ~ firstName ^^ {case (l ~ f) => Name(f, l)}
```

However, although this will compile and combine the way you want, it won't parse what you want it to. I got this output when I tried:

```
[1.1] failure: string matching regex `"([^"\p{Cntrl}\\]|\\[\\/bfnrt]|\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})*"' expected but `S' found

Schmo, Joe
^
```

`stringLiteral` expects something that looks like a string literal in code (something in quotation marks). (`JavaTokenParsers` is meant to parse stuff that looks like Java.) This works:

```
scala> val x = new NameParser
x: NameParser = NameParser@1ea8dbd

scala> x.parseAll(x.name, "\"Schmo\", \"Joe\"")
res0: x.ParseResult[Name] = [1.15] parsed: Name("Joe","Schmo")
```

You should probably replace it with a regex that specifies what kind of strings you will accept for names. If you look at the documentation [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/JavaTokenParsers.html), you'll see:

```
implicit def regex (r: Regex) : Parser[String]

A parser that matches a regex string
```

So you can just put a `Regex` object there and it will be converted into a parser that matches it.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that ``JavaTokenParsers#stringLiteral`` is probably not what's desired here.

Comment: Thanks! for the answer in general, and for pointing out about stringLiteral in particular. What can I replace stringLiteral for using the input without quotes.

Answer (score 7):

the `~>` combinator ignores the left side and the `<~` combinator ignores the right side. So the result of `lastName <~ "," ~> firstName` can never include the results of both `firstName` and `lastName`. Actually it is only the parse result of `lastName` because `"," ~> firstName` is ignored. You need to use sequential composition here:

```
lazy val name: Parser[Name] =         
  lastName ~ "," ~ firstName ^^ {case (l ~_~ f) => Name(f, l)}
```

Or if you want a prettier pattern match:

```
lazy val name: Parser[Name] =         
  lastName ~ ("," ~> firstName) ^^ {case (l ~ f) => Name(f, l)}
```

Answer (score 4):

The code

```
lastName <~ "," ~> firstName
```

will end up throwing away the result of parsing `firstName`.  Because of the operator precedence rules in Scala, the statement is parsed as if it were parenthesized like so:

```
lastName <~ ("," ~> firstName)
```

but even if it were grouped differently you are still only dealing with three parsers and throwing away the result of two of them.

So you end up with a `String` being passed into your mapping function, which is written to expect a `~[String, String]` instead.  That's why you get the compiler error you do.

One helpful technique for troubleshooting this sort of thing is to add ascriptions to subexpressions:

```
lazy val name: Parser[Name] =
  ((lastName <~ "," ~> firstName): Parser[String ~ String]) ^^ { case l ~ f => Name(f, l) }
```

which can help you to determine where exactly reality and your expectations diverge.